# Why does not work clearForm() in my code in JS?

Tags: javascript

> This program takes values of name, price, category and so on and after
>   that the form should be clear but it does not work

```
function addProduct()
{
        var product =
        {
            name:productNameInput.value,
            price:productPriceInput.value,
            category:productCategoryInput.value,
            desc:productDescriptionInput.value

        }
        productsContainer.push(product);
        localStorage.setItem("Products",JSON.stringify(productsContainer));
        displayProducts();  
        clearForm();
}
```

```
 <div class="container py-5">
           <label>Product Name:</label>
           <input type="text" name=" " id="productNameInput" class="my-2 form-control">
           <label>Product Price:</label>
           <input type="number" name=" " id="productPriceInput" class="my-2 form-control">

           <label>Product Category:</label>
           <input type="text" name=" " id="productCategoryInput" class="my-2 form-control">
           <label>Product Description:</label>
           <textarea name=" " id="productDescriptionInput" class="my-2 form-control">   
             </textarea>
             <button id ="addBtn"class="btn btn-info">Add Product</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: you should add clearForm code and HTML to question too

Comment: @HienNguyen i did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need wrap HTML to form tag  `<form id="myform">`

and add button `type="button` `<button type="button" onclick="addProduct()"`,

Your clearForm should only call reset() function as

```
function clearForm(){
  document.getElementById("myform").reset();
}
```

```js
var productsContainer = [];
function addProduct()
    {
        var product =
        {
            name:productNameInput.value,
            price:productPriceInput.value,
            category:productCategoryInput.value,
            desc:productDescriptionInput.value

        }
        productsContainer.push(product);
        //localStorage.setItem("Products",JSON.stringify(productsContainer));
        displayProducts();  
        clearForm();
    }
    
   function displayProducts(){
    }
    
function clearForm(){
  document.getElementById("myform").reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="myform"> 
 <div class="container py-5">
           <label>Product Name:</label>
           <input type="text" name=" " id="productNameInput" class="my-2 form-control">
           <label>Product Price:</label>
           <input type="number" name=" " id="productPriceInput" class="my-2 form-control">

           <label>Product Category:</label>
           <input type="text" name=" " id="productCategoryInput" class="my-2 form-control">
           <label>Product Description:</label>
           <textarea name=" " id="productDescriptionInput" class="my-2 form-control">   
             </textarea>
             <button type="button" onclick="addProduct()" id ="addBtn"class="btn btn-info">Add Product</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```